# How can I run grunt on AppHarbor through MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, gruntjs, appharbor

I can build my solution with MSBuild. It runs grunt and generates a "dist" folder within the solution directory, and MSBuild then copy those files to `$(OutDir)`.

Let's say my solution is called  `MySolution.sln`. I have next to it another file called `after.MySolution.sln.targets` which contains

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Grunt" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="grunt build --no-color" WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />

        <ItemGroup>
            <DistFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist\**\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(DistFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\www\%(RecursiveDir)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

When AppHarbor builds the solution, I receive this error

```
Grunt:
    grunt build --no-color
    'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Which is understandable, if grunt-cli was not already made available by AppHarbor. How then can I run my grunt build on AppHarbor?

*Note: Technically, to run grunt successfully, I need to run `npm install` and `bower install`, so kudos if the answer also covers grunt packages and bower packages!*

Answer (score 2):

In order to run my build, I had to use node directly rather than grunt-cli. My MSBuild now simply calls run-grunt.bat, which contains:

```
@echo off
echo Installing npm dependencies
call npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
call npm install
echo Running bower.commands.install()
call node -e "var b = require('bower'); b.commands.install()"
echo Running grunt.cli()
call node -e "var g = require('grunt'); g.cli.tasks = ['build']; g.cli.options.color = false; g.cli();"
```

It seems to work; the next issue is that node on the build servers is still at version 0.6.10, but that's another problem :)

Note that I add the registry because otherwise it didn't work (I'll have to check with AppHarbor), and since I use bower and probably other people will too, I included in my example how to run `bower install`.

Important: you'll need to include grunt (and bower if you use it) in your `packages.json` file!

Comment: Very sorry for the downvote - it was unintentional, supposed to be an upvote but I only realised too late